# MVC 5 Ajax request - controller action is not being called

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I have *.json file structured like:

```
[{ val1: "a1", val2: "b1", val3: "c1"},{ val1: "a2", val2: "b2", val3: "c2"},{ val1: "a3", val2: "b3", val3: "c3"}]
```

I have to pass that data to the View, where I have a data table that accept JSON.

I created Model class:

```
public class Values {
    public string val1 { get; set; }
    public string val2 { get; set; }
    public string val3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Home Controller:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"data.json");

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveTempSelectedPlan(string jsonString)
        {
            List<Values> vals = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Values>>(jsonString);
            return Json(vals);
        }  
    }
```

And finally in view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '@Url.Action("SaveTempSelectedPlan", "Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '[{ "val1" : ' + data.val1 + ', "val2" : ' + data.val2 + ', "val3" : ' + data.val3 '}]',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                alert(data);
                var returnJson = data;
            }
    });
});
```

So this code doesn't work, the controller action is not being called, can't fill up `var returnJson` with JSON. What should I change?

Comment: I believe my answer as it is now would work.

Comment: you can also change your string to just a var and see if that works for you. var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"data.json");

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT sending JSON but your jQuery AJAX says it's json.  Your controller is expecting a string, everybody is confused so either change your controller action or change your javascript to send text, you are telling jQuery it's json but your controller is expecting string.

So change controller to accept an object and change your js to send json object:

```
  var dataVar = [{ val1: data.val1, val2: data.val2, val3: data.val3 }];

  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '@Url.Action("SaveTempSelectedPlan", "Home")',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: dataVar,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            alert(data);
            var returnJson = data;
        }
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult SaveTempSelectedPlan(Values[] vals)
  {
     ....   
  }
```

or leave your controller as is and change your javascript to send text instead of json:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '@Url.Action("SaveTempSelectedPlan", "Home")',
        data: '[{ "val1" : ' + data.val1 + ', "val2" : ' + data.val2 + ', "val3" : ' + data.val3 '}]',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            alert(data);
            var returnJson = data;
        }
```

Comment: I did as u suggested, but the ajax request doesn't seems to work I added additional to the request: error: function() { alert("Error"); but didn't get any respond.

Comment: instead of sending an array of `Values` on your controller, change it to just send `Values` (no array) and see if you can get it firing.

Comment: that would mean changing the js var `dataVar` to be just an object and not an array also.

Comment: Still nothing, I'm not even getting an alerts after View loads, where should I look for the problem ?

Comment: make sure the controller is firing, go back to simple.  harcode the ajax `url: "/Home/SaveTempSelectedPlan"`  simplify and see where things stop working

Comment: I'm dealing with the problem since a few hours already... Is there any better way to send JSON array to java script code on my View site ?